# image grows when scrolling uitableview

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

i have a big problem . in my app, when you touch a textfield it comes above the keyboard and my tableview scroll up and my image in the tableview too.

it works well. But when i use de return key the tableview scroll down the textfield too but  my image gets larger when scrolling is over the image returns to its correct size

the code for return key:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

[messageField resignFirstResponder];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 323, 320, 44);
dialogueTb.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 372);
[UIView commitAnimations];
return YES;
```

}

EDIT:

I found the problem in my textFieldShouldReturn:

no problem if i do this:

```
 -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

[messageField resignFirstResponder];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 323, 320, 44);
[UIView commitAnimations];<<====================== change place
dialogueTb.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 372);
//[UIView commitAnimations] 
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it has something to do with the autoresizingMask of the UIImageView. Try this:

```
imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
```